# Fastest way to solve long polynomial with lots of different powers

Tags: python, performance, math, optimization, package

I'm looking for the fastest solution, x, to this polynomial equation:

Let m be an element in set M.

sum over all m {a_m * x^(b_m) - c_m * x^(b_m - 1)} = 0, where a_m, b_m, c_m are all different for each m. The set M has ~15-20 elements.

If the solution is > 4, it will return 4. If the solution is < 0, it will return 0.
What is the fastest way to do this? Doing it numerically?

I would prefer a solution in python, and other languages only if it's very beneficial to switch.

Note this is the derivative of an objective function. I am just trying to maximize the objective function, so if there's a better way to do it aside from solving this polynomial, that would work too! The solution should be fairly fast, as I am trying to solve many of these objective functions.

Comment: Can we assume that the elements of M are all positive?

Comment: Scipy's optimize package (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) might let you address the maximization problem directly, although I think optimization problems are usually cast finding minima. The same package also has root finding routines (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#root-finding).

Comment: the elements in set M aren't numbers, they are just there to subscript the constants a, b, c as each one is different for each different m. a_m can be negative or positive. b_m and c_m are both negative. The roots are going to be prices, so complex roots don't really help me. In fact, I am not allowed to charge prices > 4, so I guess if a root is > 4, I will just use 4 as the optimal solution.

Comment: Do you know the function has only one root in the interval (0,4)?  Also, if (as you commented) the exponents b_m are negative, then the function you want to find "the" solution to is not polynomial.  If the exponents are integers, however, you can convert to a polynomial root finding problem on x > 0 by multiplying the function by a sufficiently large power of x.

Comment: You could try posting this at the new [scicomp](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com) site, if the answers here are not satisfactory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only looking for one root and not all roots, you can use [Newton's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), which I expect is reasonably fast for the polynomials you've described.

let f(x) = sum over all m {`a*x^(b) - c*x^(b-1)`}

then f'(x), the derivative of f(x), is the sum over all m {`(a*b)*x^(b-1) - (c*(b-1))*x^(b-2)`}.

```
def newton(f, fprime, firstguess, epsilon):
    x = firstguess
    while abs(f(x)) > epsilon:
        x = x - (f(x) / fprime(x))
    return x
```

This will return an approximate root to your polynomial. If it's not accurate enough, pass in a smaller epsilon until it is accurate enough.

Note that this function may diverge, and run forever, or throw a ZeroDivisionError. Handle with caution.